# Get selection index of dialog_menu in dialog (libdialog)

Tags: c, dialog, stdout, ncurses

I am implementing a small dialog system using [`dialog`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/) in C and have been reading the documentation [here](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.pdf) but cannot figure out how to get the selection index of the `dialog_menu` command.

I understand the `init_dialog(FILE *, FILE *)` function is taking `stdout` as an output here but then I don't believe it is possible to redirect the output to a variable anyway.

When running this code, pressing the "Exit" button returns code 1, while pressing either of the two options returns 0. How can I differentiate between these selections?

```c
#include <dialog.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr)[0]))

int
menu()
{
    int select;
    char *modes[] =
    {
        "1", "The first option",
        "2", "The second option"
    };

    init_dialog(stdin, stdout);
    select = dialog_menu("test_app", "Choose an option.", 0, 0, 0, LEN(modes) / 2, modes);
    end_dialog();

    return select;
}

int
main()
{
    int status;
    status = menu();
    printf("%d\n", status);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dialog` library contains a struct called `dialog_vars` which contains among many things, a variable `char *input_result`.

When a selection is made in the menu, `input_result` is set to the value of the *tag*, (in the provided source code, this tag being either `"1"` or `"2"` and if no selection is made at all, the `NULL` pointer.

From here, a `strcmp` can be done to determine which response was selected.

**PS:** Always ensure to call `dlg_clr_result()` before repeated dialogs because the choice is *concatenated* to `input_result` and thus by not calling the function, the new result will be appended onto the old one instead of replacing it.

Example:

```c
#include <dialog.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr)[0]))

void
menu()
{
    char *modes[] =
    {
        "1", "The first option",
        "2", "The second option"
    };

    init_dialog(stdin, stdout);
    dialog_menu("test_app", "Choose an option.", 0, 0, 0, LEN(modes) / 2, modes);
    end_dialog();

    char *result = dialog_vars.input_result; /* this will be "1", "2" or NULL */

    init_dialog(stdin, stdout);
    dialog_menu("test_app", strcmp(result, "1") ? "One" : "Two", 0, 0, 1);
    end_dialog();
}

int
main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```